# How to get Facebook comments for a page on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I can use Facebook login to login as an admin of the Facebook app that represents my website. Then, I can call this endpoint:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?access_token=".$tokens["access_token"]."&ids=".$source
```

here, `$tokens["access_token"]` is an access token provided by the Facebook login process and `$source` is the URL for which I want to get the comments.

Facebook's API response is this:

> To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be
>   reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content
>   Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable
>   features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

Initiating the review process for my app in the Facebook developer dashboard, the requirement for obtaining access for this is:

> Please give them detailed step-by-step instructions for how to **see**
>   this permission the same way people using your app would.

And:

> We need to see your app using Page Public Content Access so we can
>   **see** that it doesn't violate our policies. Upload a video screencast walkthrough using any method, (even recording with your
>   phone).

(In both cases, the emphasis is mine.)

I can not show what I can not show. I have no access to this endpoint, so I can not show, in action, my site using this endpoint.

What's more, I am the admin of the Facebook app representing the website for which I want to get access to the comments, and want to access the comments through that, my, account, only; I don't want any regular user account to access the comments for the pages on my website.

So, how do I get programmatic access to the Facebook comments made on pages on my website?

Comment: do you manage those pages? if not, why would you want to put comments of pages you don´t manage on your own website?

Comment: If you are admin of the page, you don’t need PPCA. Just request `manage_pages` permission, and use your admin access token or a page token. (The latter probably preferable, because an extended one does not have any default expiry.)

Comment: @luschn: These are URLs of my website, tied to an app for which I am a manager (or admin, or whatever it's called).

Comment: @CBroe: The 'pages' in question are the pages of my website, not a page related to my website on Facebook. Adding the manage_pages permission sadly didn't make a difference.

Comment: Then you should not be getting any errors mentioning Page Public Content Access either … For example a request for [`?ids=http://example.com/`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&version=v3.0) works fine for me using any app id.

Comment: @CBroe. So, then, either I'm doing something wrong, or there's something wrong on the Facebook side. Though the latter is certainly possible, it's somewhat more likely the error is mine. Have you access to a working example of obtaining the Facebook comments on a webpage connected to a Facebook app?